# Javascript add function call with parameters to button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add a function call including parameters to a HTML button via javascript. I know there are plenty of questions to this subject but none of the answers i found did work for me.

Note: My HTML and JS are in separate files which are correctly linked (the JS code works)

Problem:
I can add the function call like this:

```
var $add  = $("#add");
$add.click(myFunction);
```

However `$add.click(myFunction(i));` does not work.(Did also try with specific integer)

I have also tried it the following way:

```
document.getElementById('add').onclick = function() {myFunction(i);};
```

But like that the function does not even get applied to the button.

My function is defined in the JS file like this:

```
function myFunction(length) {

//do stuff with length I would notice

}
```

Comment: Title says 'div', question says 'button'. Both should work, but I'd chose 'button'.

Comment: edited, thanks for the note

Comment: Can you show the complete code snippet. How / where are you defining `i`?

Comment: I was mostly testing it with `myFunction(1)` instead of `i` and that did not work either, so i dont think that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some thing like function bind or do it using handler:

```
$add.click(function(e){
  myFunction(i);
});
```

Comment: works like a charm, thank you! Could you explain why this works and mine did not work ?

Comment: you are used this : 
$add.click(myFunction(i))

So you are binding the return value of executed function **myFunction** not the function itself, binding is used for functions only. there is a deference between these two:

var a = myFunction;var b = myFunction(i);

//a: is a reference for function object, b:  is the returned value from the called function.

$add.click(handler) a function object to be abound with the click event.
and it will called like : handler(e) //where e is the event object data triggered by the event