# javascript add data in name function call

Tags: javascript

Searching but, idk what really main keyword i must search..

Other searching keyword

[Javascript add function call with parameters to button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709637/javascript-add-function-call-with-parameters-to-button)

[How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

The problem is :

```
$("#poi_list").change(function ()  {
 var poi_id = $("#poi_list").val();
 alert(poi_id);
 poiPath+poi_id+.setMap(map);
});
```

My question is, how i call a function like poiPath5.setMap(map);

The number i get from poi_id is dynamic, the number is more than thousand(this other problem, but now i just wanna solve this problem)

Any thought?

Comment: did you mean to write `poiPath[poi_id].setMap(map);` or is it `window['poiPath' + poi_id].setMap(map)` - assuming `poiPath#` are global variables

Comment: no. i mean, how i call poiPath5.setMap(map); 5 is dynamic data from val..

Comment: see edited comment - works only if `poiPath#` are globals though - you could use `eval` in this case too

Comment: I think what you want to do is write a jquery extension...not super sure though. Hard to understand the question.

Comment: wew, yep, it's duplicated.. lol..